# Align based on button action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I align an image based on a position of a button when an onclick event is triggered?

Example: Assume there are 2 buttons with id btnA and btnB. When btnA is clicked the image should align to the centre of btnA. If btnB is clicked the image should move and align to the centre of btnB.

```
<img id = "markerz" src="img/marker.png"/>
<a class="cBtn" id= "btnA" onclick="markerPos(btnA);">Button1</a>
<a class="cBtn" id= "btnB" onclick="markerPos(btnA);">Button2</a>

    <script>
    function markerPos(BUTTONinUSE){
       document.getElementById(markerz).style.align = (document.getElementById(BUTTONinUSE)="center");
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get positions and sizes of buttons, position and sizes of image and change position of image.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        img {
            position:relative;
        }
        .clear {
            clear:both;
        }
        a {
            padding:20px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <img id = "markerz" src="marker.png"></img>
        <a class="cBtn" id= "btnA" onclick="markerPos(this);">Button1</a>
        <a class="cBtn" id= "btnB" onclick="markerPos(this);">Button2</a>
        <script>
            'use strict';
            var marker = document.getElementById('markerz'),
                markerWidth = marker.offsetWidth,
                markerLeft  = marker.offsetLeft,
                markerPos = function (target) {
                    var left = target.offsetLeft,
                        selfWidth = target.offsetWidth,
                        centerWidth = left + selfWidth/2,
                        horDiff = markerLeft + markerWidth/2 - centerWidth;
                    marker.style.left = (markerLeft - horDiff) + 'px';
                };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the image at the start? Centered? Then you want to click it so goes to one button or the other?
You can use the button to apply/remove css.

html:

```
<div id="iMove" class="center">
<img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/zakar/shining-z/128/ballon-SZ-icon.png"        />
 </div>
<div class="ui-grid-b">
<div class="ui-block-a"><a data-role="button" id="btnA">Click</a></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"></div>
<div class="ui-block-c"><a data-role="button" id="btnB">Click</a></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.center {
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.right {
display: block;
text-align: right;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.left {
display: block;
text-align: left;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

jquery

```
$("#btnB").on("click", function(){
$("#iMove").removeClass();
$("#iMove").addClass('right');

});

$("#btnA").on("click", function(){
$("#iMove").removeClass();
$("#iMove").addClass('left');
});
```

see the jFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yw6LE/5/)

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you

```
var btnWidth = $(".cBtn").outerWidth(); // Use Outer Width to get all button width include padding


$(".cBtn").click(function(){

var tid = $(this).attr('id');

var btnPos = $("#"+tid).offset().left; // Get the X pos of button

var btnCenterX = btnPos + (btnWidth / 2); // Get the X center pos of button , ( x = offsetXbtn + (btnwidth / 2 )  )

var imgXcenter = $("#markerz").width() / 2; // Get center X pos for image


$("#markerz").css({left : btnCenterX + "px"}) // Image X pos will align to the center of button


//$("#markerz").css({left : (btnCenterX - imgXcenter) + "px"}) Enable this to get image center align with button

})
```

Sorry if my English  is bad :)

NOTE : I used jQuery

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AzK76/)